# Maven build not download all needed files

Tags: maven, build

I have a maven build what should download some jar files form the same directory in nexus.
There are

```
myproduct_model-1.32-SNAPSHOT.jar
and
myproduct_model-1.32-SNAPSHOT-liquibase.jar
```

The build successfully download the first one but not the second. 
How can I force that?

Comment: This both files can not be in the same directory in Nexus. because of different "Version number "

Comment: Thank you. What can I do to separate them?

Comment: put it into specific Directory and than add both files as dependency

Comment: Can I define the target directory in the .pom file or needed the java developers help?

Comment: Show us your pom.xml. Then we might spot the problem.

Comment: Which pom? Im using a pom for generating he myproduct_model. Or the pom what Im using for deployment?

Comment: I Put the related part from the deployment pom.xml here: https://pastebin.com/kE6rntBB

Comment: Those two files can be in the same directory cause they use the same version but the other file is using a classifier...You can't use `copy-dependencies` cause this would mean having two dependencies with the same GAV (groupId, artifactId, version)..this needs the `copy` goal to copy those artifact...Apart from that I would suggest not to try scripting this kind via Maven better take a look if you can create a distribution zip before and download only the zip file later it's easier...

Comment: @khmarbaise: Please describe me this zip creation idea. When careate and how? Do you have a link or smthng else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `<classifier>` element on your dependencies, such as:

```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.deltabasics</groupId>
      <artifactId>myproduct_model</artifactId>
      <version>${version-myproduct_model}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.deltabasics</groupId>
      <artifactId>myproduct_model</artifactId>
      <version>${version-myproduct_model}</version>
      <classifier>liquibase</classifier>
  </dependency>
```

This will make Maven download both dependencies even if they use the same version as the classifier is different. If you want these dependencies to be download in your project `target` directory, use the maven-dependency-plugin with the same method:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>copy</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>copy</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <artifactItems>
                        <artifactItem>
                            <groupId>com.deltabasics</groupId>
                            <artifactId>myproduct_model</artifactId>
                            <version>${version-myproduct_model}</version>
                            <type>jar</type>
                        </artifactItem>
                        <artifactItem>
                            <groupId>com.deltabasics</groupId>
                            <artifactId>myproduct_model</artifactId>
                            <version>${version-myproduct_model}</version>
                            <type>jar</type>
                            <classifier>liquibase</classifier>
                        </artifactItem>
                    </artifactItems>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
     </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Thank you. I will check it on Monday

Comment: @GergA did that solution gave you the expected results?

Comment: Unfortunately Not. I got the following error
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.0.2:copy (copy) on project qa-system-deployment-qa: Unable to find/resolve artifact. Could not find artifact com.deltabasics:myproduct_model:jar:liquibase:1.32-SNAPSHOT

 "org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.0.2:copy (copy) on project qa-system-deployment-qa: Unable to find/resolve artifact.",

Comment: I added it to the following section
 <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>

Comment: You mentionned both files are available on Nexus, but this error probably means that `myproduct_model-1.32-SNAPSHOT-liquibase.jar` is not available on your Nexus repo. At least it tries to download it, so that's a step forward ;) Does it work on your local machine? If yes, it is probably due to your QA server not properly configured configured for your Nexus repo. If not, make sure the file exists on Nexus repo and can be downloaded from your QA server.

Comment: Im not sure how it is workin gbut when I go to the nexus I can go to the following directory `com/deltabasics/myproduct_model/1.32-SNAPSHOT/`
The problem is , the file names inside of this folder doesn't contains the SNAPSHOT word. Here is the format `myproduct_model-1.32-20171027.075848-9-liquibase.jar`. Lot of jars.  I don't know how the latest changes to SNAPSHOT

Comment: That's probably because each SNAPSHOT versions of your jars are deployed as independent versions with unique numbering to preserve history, that's common in build processes. If you are not familiar with what a SNAPSHOT version is and how it is used I recommend you do a little research ;) to properly use your build, you'll have to specify an existing version such as `1.32-20171027.075848-9` but as you are on the QA server you'll probably want to avoid SNAPSHOT and use a release or release candidate version, such as `1.32` or `1.32-RELEASE` and make sure it is deployed on Nexus.

Comment: I inherited this environment. :-). Yes I need to learn how is it working. Besides , how can I solve my issue which is download the latest version of the snapshot and rename it?

Comment: You can try using Maven dependency range, but I would recommand either specifying a specific version for your tests (such as `1.32-20171027.075848-9`) or having your build deploy a fixed snapshot version such as `1.32-SNAPSHOT` so you can use it safely in your other projects to have the most recent snapshot versions.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to add the following rows

```
     <dependency>
          <groupId>com.deltabasics</groupId>
          <artifactId>myproduct_model</artifactId>
          <version>${version-myproduct_model}-liquibase</version>
      </dependency>
```

Unfortunately the maven made the other folder instead of downloading.

Comment: You mean as per my previous answer? (please use comment instead of answer then ;) ). I don't understand what you mean by "made the other folder instead of downloading"

Comment: NoNo. This is my old answer where I tried to show what I did before. :-)